# Bootstrap 3 : table-responsive inside display:table-cell doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a scenario where I have a Bootstrap 3 table-responsive inside 2 divs. One div is set to display:table and the other set to diaplay:table-cell. This seems to break the responsive table.

Here is a simple example:

```
<div style="display:table;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Table heading</th>
                    <th>Table heading</th>
                    <th>Table heading</th>
                    <th>Table heading</th>
                    <th>Table heading</th>
                    <th>Table heading</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

If you remove the table display, table works as should.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you doing `table` and `table-cell`?

Comment: @Daniel, because the layout needs 100% height, so using the css display: table for that.

Comment: Hi creimers, any solutions?

Comment: I have the same problem, I created a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/ichr/bwh36xm5/5/ it seems that bootstrap 3 .table-responsive wrapper is not working as expected in this layout.

Comment: Here is almost the same problem. I suggested a solution. Reed my answer, it works! : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394072/bootstrap-3-table-table-responsive-not-working/43954934#43954934