# Bootstrap 3 table - table-responsive not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, html-table

I'm using bootstrap 3 for a website project. I'm trying to create a page with a responsive table, so that I'd have the scrollbar when the table is too big. I made a test case like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <h4>Nuværende kurser</h4>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end col-12 -->
</div><!-- end row -->
```

Now, the problem is that it doesn't add the scrollbar, it merely expands the website to the width of the table.

See a screenshot here:

[image]

I've seen it working on several other websites, so something I'm doing...is wrong.

Comment: So, do  you want there to be a horisontal scrollbar for the table?

Comment: Your use of table-responsive is correct and it should be working. BTW it's completely unnecessary to use col-12 (not a bootstrap class), co-sm-12, col-lg-12 and the row. No grid classes are needed on full width elements unless you are using a background color on them.

Comment: @DanielOlsen Did you figure this out eventually? I find that I'm having the same issue when using display:table as a container for table-responsive.

Comment: have you included the less and sass file of bootstrap

Comment: I have a website project with all the files hosted on my own server instead of CDN. But on localhost it doesn't show the table responsively but it shows on server. I don't know what is the mystery. All imports including CSS, JS works correctly on both localhost on server.

Answer (score 56):

Replace your table-responsive with this

```
<div class='table-responsive'> -> <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
```

Comment: Do you know why the original .table-responsive does not work ?

Answer (score 18):

Make sure to set your table display **block**

```css
.table {
   display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

bootstrap's table-responsive works fine in sandbox environments, but it is buggy on live environments. The reason for the bug is that bootstrap gives table-responsive styles of width: 100% and overflow-y: hidden. These two styles do not play nice together. Overflow hiding works best when there is a fixed or max-width. I gave table-responsive a max-width: 270px; for mobile devices, and that fixed the bug.

Answer (score 3):

You're code is fine.  I just set up a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/q27gzvot/).

Works there!

I literally copied and pasted your code.  Are you sure your links to Bootstrap's Javascript file and CSS file are working?

```
<div class="row">
 <h4>Nuværende kurser</h4>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div><!-- end col-12 -->
  </div><!-- end row -->
```

Comment: It worked fine for me too. I also think it could be the bootstrap js file link.

Comment: @Carlton there's something else wrong, probably a missing div somewhere else on the page. .table-responsive is only css, nothing to do with js

Comment: I guess there is something else blocking it. Cause I can set up a fiddle as well, and it works fine, but on MY page, its not working at all...

Comment: A fieldset tag was making havoc for me

Comment: The jsfiddle link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

I'v done it.

```
<div style="display: table">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell">


            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">


                       //wrapper that will give opportunity to use: overflow-x: auto; 
                       <table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
                           <tr>
                               <td>


                                  //SCROLL
                                  <div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;">

                                      //table, that shoud have "table-responsive" bootstrap class effect
                                      <table class="table table-hover">

                                          //...table content...

                                      </table>

                                  </div>


                               <td>
                           </tr>

                       </table>                           


                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will receive at xs-screen (example from my app):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and found that it worked to either give the table a set width in px, or to set the table to display: block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FooTable. It is a jQuery plugin that allows you to resize and redistribute the data within your tables to best suite your current breakpoint.

Comment: Links to third party plugins and applications are generally frowned upon by the SO community. SO is geared more towards getting help debugging your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the 'min-width' value in body element breaking the responsiveness of this class.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define height in px or rem not percent for closest div actually. in your code define height for closest parent div to table-responsive div and make sure to do not use percent value

Answer (score -1):

Try this
remove `<div class="table-responsive">...</div>`
and move class table-responsive in 
`<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">`

example 
`<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 table-responsive">` 
this 100% work but if dont work move class table-responsive to Earlier Div layer,
In this case,
 `<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">` 
must be removed.

Comment: you cannot mix the styling classes with the grid classes. You set yourself up for potential issues in the future which will be hard to debug

Answer (score -1):

In my code, I did add a CSS class:

```
.modal-body{
  max-width:95vw;
}
```

The layout did work for `sm`