# Boostrap responsive table is not responsive inside a "table"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a responsive table inside the div that display as table

Example code:

```
<div class="mytable">
    <div class="mycolumn">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                .....
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.mytable{
    display: table;
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.mycolumn{
    display: table-cell;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6L6owp7x/

The problem is that the responsive table is not responsive at all when inside the "table" div. How can I get it to be responsive?

Comment: Here is almost the same problem. I suggested a solution. Reed my answer, it works!  :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394072/bootstrap-3-table-table-responsive-not-working/43954934#43954934

Answer (score 0):

One of the quickest ways is to set the td,th { width: 1%}  I don't think you are looking for a responsive table inside i think you want a justified table which there are some how tos out there how to do that.  Remember bootstrap is setting widths on these at certain break points so the smaller breakpoints won't respond on this without media queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with your `td,th { width: 1%}`, but it seems to be doesn't work. Yes, I want the table to be responsive as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried table-responsive class of bootstrap and it worked  Here's an example

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/responsive/