# Yii2 grid view not responsive

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-basic-app

i have grid view and add clas table responsive like this

```
<div class="card-box table-responsive">
        <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'options' => ['class' => 'table-responsive'],
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                'id',
                'username',
                'kode_role',
                'kode_karyawan',
                'auth_key',
                'password_hash',
                'password_reset_token',
                'email:email',
                [
                    'header' => 'status',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'value' => function($dataProvider){
                        if($dataProvider->status == '5') {
                            return'<span class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Tidak Aktif</span>';
                        }elseif ($dataProvider->status == '10') {
                            return '<span class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Aktif</span>';
                        }
                    }
                ],
                'created_at',
                'updated_at',
                'verification_token',
            ],
        ]); ?>


    </div>
```

please don't mind about what i show on grid view, i just show many of them for test responsive on mobile, but the result still not responsive on mobile like this picture
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izGkL.png)
what's wrong with my code? sorry for my bad English.

[image]

1. Update i delete the hash and the other that have many character and
   stil like this [update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcIBi.png)
   [image]

Comment: Try using normal text instead of long hashes which don't have any spaces in them so the browser doesn't know where to wrap them. Possibly related to https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Comment: its still same exceed the container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 3 table - table-responsive not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394072/bootstrap-3-table-table-responsive-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/32013813/16340676

"The reason for the bug is that bootstrap gives table-responsive styles of width: 100% and overflow-y: hidden. These two styles do not play nice together. Overflow hiding works best when there is a fixed or max-width. I gave table-responsive a max-width: 270px; for mobile devices, and that fixed the bug."

the solution just add a max-width in my table-responsive css