# CSS - Table Responsive inside display:table + display:table-row/cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

Im currently working on a project with a company where we need to display data in a table. Some queries retrieve so many fields that the output table quickly overflow. The problem is that their template uses display:table and display:table-row and such for vertical-align, sticky footers and some other viewport tricks.

This template is based on Bootsrap3. When working with the responsive table it just won't work. No matter what CSS I try to fix it, either changing its display or changing the overflow rules, etc.

I've found two questions that describe the exact same problem though they are unanswered.

[Bootstrap 3 : table-responsive inside display:table-cell doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640190/bootstrap-3-table-responsive-inside-displaytable-cell-doesnt-work)

[Boostrap responsive table is not responsive inside a "table"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692323/boostrap-responsive-table-is-not-responsive-inside-a-table)

You can look at the code there, it's simple. Just bootstrap's table-responsive wrapped around display:table-row inside display:table.

Of course if I remove both displays this solves the problem but creates much worse problems all around the layout because everything is coded around this display:table.

So I'm looking for a solution that doesn't break the layout. "Keep the displays as it is" while fixing table-responsive problem by styling it or something. I've spend hours trying to fix this and doing research but I've had no luck so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Key to solution is to set `width: 100%` and `table-layout: fixed` to table element used in your template's layout (you'll still be able to use rubber columns, sticky footers etc) to get your responsive tables work.
Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/vgoma/pen/EoKmGx). Try to disable one of these properties and you'll get your issue displayed.